# Как сделать что бы в ActionBar менялось значение пункта меню ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, actionbar

Здравствуйте. У меня есть ActionBar с одним пунктом "Корзина". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовал я это так:

menu/main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/backet"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку - изменялся вид корзины?

Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо !!!

Comment: https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge

Comment: А еще как-нибудь ?